# Pages redirecting to homepage

Tags: pages, child-pages

I have run into an issue with pages on my site. All pages, except child pages redirect to the homepage. I have reset the permalinks several times, so I don't think that is the main issue or concern. All posts and child pages work fine and there are not issues there.

I have created a 'quick fix' by creating a default page called 'page' and have now put all existing pages as a child of 'page'. My issue or concern is that this is a quick fix and is not sustainable in the future of the site.

I have seen everyone refer to the .htaccess file, however, I don't have access to this file. I also don't think this is the culprit as the all other permalinks work fine.

If anyone comes across this and has any idea of how to resolve this issue without a full WP re-install, I would be stoked.

The site is [teche.ltc.mq.edu.au](http://teche.ltc.mq.edu.au)

Comment: can you give some more details about the settings of the page? Interesting would be for example `Administration > Settings > Reading > Front Page displays` and your permalinks settings. I see that you are using a child theme of twentfourteen. Does the problem also happen when using twentyfourteen? Did you try to deactivate all plugins? To me it looks that somehow always `home.php` is used as template, because trying to get nonexistent pages also shows the front page's content instead of using the '404.php' template.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, busy end of year. Yeah the same issue happens when using the twentyfourteen theme. It still happens even after deactivating all plugins.

Comment: There are lots of pages, all with content. I'm not sure why home.php is being called. It just started happening.